# Bat file to remove all user folders with 20 in the name bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I just started working in a school and the way we have the computers set up they automatically download a students user from the network when a student logs into any computer. We're working on making a script to run this command for cleaning them :

```
for /D %f in (*20**) do rmdir %f /s /q
```

In command prompt it shows every user with 20 in the name and deletes them from the computer along with everything in these folders.

We can't just change the file name to .bat instead of storing it in a note pad to copy to a command prompt window.

The batch file we currently have is

```
@echo off
pause
for /d %%f in (*20**) do rmdir C:\Users\%%f /s /q 

pause
```

Which shows each pause to try to help me debug it but doesn't delete the folder. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Change your `rmdir C:\Users\%%f /s /q` to `echo C:\Users\%%f`. What output do you get?

Comment: I don't get any output. Just the pause prompts. The user I'm testing this script to get it to delete is named fakeuser2020.

Comment: If you're getting no output, it means your for loop isn't finding anything. What do you expect `*20**` to do? What does typing `*20**` at a command prompt do?

Comment: In command prompt I get `C:\Users>echo C:\Users\fakeuser2020`
`C:\Users\fakeuser2020`

Comment: Type `dir *20**` into the batch file immediately before the `pause` command and tell us what is returned. Regard that `*20**` (which is supposed to be `*20*` I guess) is a path relative to the current working directory; given the user directories are located in `C:\Users` you should provide that root in the `for` loop, so write `for /d %%f in ("C:\Users\*20*") do`, and for the `rmdir` command line write `rmdir /s /q "%%~ff"`...

Comment: Setting up three dummy users by creating folders in `C:\Test` named user201, user202 and user203 and using `for /D %f in (*20*) do rd %f` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. For some reason I had to cd to get it to the correct file path.

Comment: `@echo off
cd \.
cd \Users\
pause
for /D %%f in (*20**) do rmdir %%f /s /q
pause`
Works but doesn't display the names of the users it deletes like it would if run in command prompt. As long as it works I'm happy though.

Comment: So basically for some reason it was having trouble finding the correct directory

Comment: *but doesn't display the names* - Of course it doesn't. You told it not to when you wrote `@echo off`, which means *don't echo commands*.

Comment: I realized this yesterday once I got home from work. It was a face-palm moment for sure! @KenWhite

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this. As I assume it's something like:

Regular%20User

%20 is basically a space.

To address your issue of wanting to clean them, as I assume it is the temp profile that is created when they login(from a network profile), rather than making the script clean anything with 20 in it, make a script that removes users locally that are of a certain Group Policy group. That way your admin accounts stay locally, and if your script is done right, your student's profiles are autocleaned after a set delay. (I would recommend 30 days, as you can use the temp profile as evidence if a student is caught on a computer he/she shouldn't be on :)

Comment: We have the students users with their graduation year in them which is why we are selecting any users with 20 in the name. (ie. firstlast2016). We only need to clean up the user accounts twice a year when we do the rest of the cleaning with the Tron 9.1.3 script which is why I did it this way. It wound up working perfectly as no other users have 20 in them.